# An object with dynamic nested keys

Tags: javascript

There is an array

```
let arr = [
    ['one','apple','acid','Lorem1'],
    ['one','strawberry','sugar','Lorem2'],
    ['two','melon','water','Lorem3'],
    ['two','melon','sugar','Lorem4'],
    ['three','cow','meat','Lorem5'],
    ['three','peeg','meat','Lorem6']
];
```

It is necessary to turn this into the following object:

```
   let obj = {
        one:{
            apple:{
                acid:{
                    title:'Lorem1'
                }
            },
            strawberry:{
                sugar:{
                    title:'Lorem2'
                }
            }
        },
        two:{
            melon:{
                water:{
                    title:'Lorem3'
                },
                sugar:{
                    title:'Lorem4'
                }
            }
        },
        three:{
            cow:{
                meat:{
                    title:'Lorem5'
                }
            },
            peeg:{
                meat:{
                    title:'Lorem6'


     }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried, but this eviction key is undefined:

```
for( row = 1; row<arr.length; row++ ) {
    obj[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]={
        title:arr[3]
    };
}
```

But since in advance indices are not defined, it produces an undefined error.

Help to find the right decision, only crutches on "if" come to mind.

Comment: If you can use the LoDash library, its [set](https://lodash.com/docs/#set) method can do that job for you. If you need to implement it yourself, then you can have a look at how it was implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code doesn't work because javascript do not automatically create empty object when use `obj[attr]` syntex, you should create it yourself.

```js
let arr = [
    ['one','apple','acid','Lorem1'],
    ['one','strawberry','sugar','Lorem2'],
    ['two','melon','water','Lorem3'],
    ['two','melon','sugar','Lorem4'],
    ['three','cow','meat','Lorem5'],
];

let obj = {}

for(let attrs of arr){
  let current = obj;
  for(let i=0;i<attrs.length-1;++i){
    if(!current[attrs[i]])
      current[attrs[i]]={}
    current=current[attrs[i]]
  }
  current['title']=attrs[attrs.length-1]
}

console.log(obj)
```